# Changing pictures on servlet with websocket

Tags: javascript, java, json, html, servlets

I have a small website that each times an user cliks on an image, it changes. It is made on HTML5, JS, Java and Wildfly. Does anyone know how do I update the image for the others users browsers as well? I mean, each time someone clicks on the image, it changes, and I want it to change on the other users that are on my website by the moment as well.
I made the connection of JavaScript and Java with JSON, but how can I send a message from Java to Javascript? With JSON again?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 2 options:

1. Client side, poll the server periodically, asking if you should get a new image; if yes, get it
2. Connect with a [websocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), and send a notification from your server to the client telling it to get a new image

Option 1 would probably be pretty easy to implement.  Create an endpoint on your backend that keeps track of the "current" image.  Your clients can hit that endpoint, and update the image if they determine it is necessary.  The disadvantage is that you will constantly be polling your server from all of your clients.

Option 2 is a bit more robust.  The websocket allows bidirectional communication.  So, on the server side you would still track a current image.  When a client clicks the image, you send a message (client->server) that notifies the backend to change the image.  Then, your server can send out a message to all the open websockets notifying them that they need to change the image.  The message you send to your clients could contain an image url or whatever information you need to display it.

Hope this helps.